# adding "is" prefix to a Boolean json request field

Tags: java, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'm using JAX-RS and Dropwizard to develop an API (I'm pretty new to both)

I want to have a json field called `isInNetwork` for example. But the strange thing for me is after defining the model and resource, I see `inNetwork` as the defined json field. (the `is` prefix is removed)

to be more specific when I define the model as:

```
@JsonProperty
private Boolean isInNetwork;
```

and when I run the server I see `"inNetwork": false`

wanted to know if that's something by default (that I'm not aware of) set by dropwizard / jax-rs for Booleans?

Comment: the first, your getter method looks like this getInNetwork,if you want to add the prefix, you should change it to getIsInNetwork.the second,Did you set his value somewhere

Comment: Yep you are right, the getter was the problem....thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use "is" prefix for the field at all, because of "is" prefix is used for getters for boolean fields. `getIsInNetwork` method name looks bad.

Better to specify JSON property name for the field

```
@JsonProperty("isInNetwork")
private Boolean inNetwork;

public Boolean isInNetwork() {
  return inNetwork;
}

public void setInNetwork(Boolean inNetwork) {
  return this.inNetwork = inNetwork;
}
```